# Ethers.js Contract call works from Brave browser but fails from Metamask Goerli Testnet

Tags: solidity, metamask, brave-browser

Contract - 0xaB9d2D124E70Be7039d7CCba9AFd06AdC1Bc60C0
All the failed transactions are called from Metamask, and all the successes are called from the Brave browser.

It's a basic, "update a contract property" call, nothing crazy.

It has always worked from Brave Browser, but I was getting *Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction* errors from Chrom/MetaMask, so I added the provider.getGasPrice()

```
async function SendMessage() {
        contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, wallet);
        let gasEst = await provider.getGasPrice();
        console.log(ethers.utils.formatUnits(gasEst, 'gwei'));
        return contract.SendRequest(message, { gasLimit: 1000000, gasPrice: gasEst });
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As per my experience, the **gasLimit** varies from blockchain to blockchain have you tried to adjust the **gasLimit**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no contract on the `0xaB9d2D...` address on the Ethereum mainnet ([Etherscan link](https://etherscan.io/address/0xaB9d2D124E70Be7039d7CCba9AFd06AdC1Bc60C0)). So when you send it a transaction on the mainnet, it's a simple transfer between two end user addresses (in your case, you're sending value of 0 ETH) and the `data` field is ignored.

However, on the Goerli testnet ([Etherscan link](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xaB9d2D124E70Be7039d7CCba9AFd06AdC1Bc60C0#code)), there is a contract deployed on this address. Assuming this contract doesn't implement the `SendRequest()` function, nor the `fallback()` special function, it rejects all incoming transfers that are trying to execute a function that is not defined in this contract (in your case `SendRequest()`).

Comment: Yes, sorry for omitting the info, it is on Goerli.  

I am moron, I had a bad copy paste and accidently left a require owner annotation on it.